# How can I track s3 bucket folder usage with python?

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3

I'm building a file hosting app that will store all client files within a folder on an S3 bucket. I then want to track the amount of usage on S3 recursively per top folder to charge back the cost of storage and bandwidth to each corresponding client.

Front-end is django but the solution can be python for obvious reasons.

Is it better to create a bucket per client programmatically?

If I do go with the approach of creating a bucket per client, is it then possible to get the cost of cloudfront exposure of the bucket if enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, there could be multiple solutions for your task. First have a look whether [Amazon DevPay](http://aws.amazon.com/devpay/) fits your needs, this should allow billing clients by their usage of EC2 and S3 resources.

Second idea is to use the [Account Activity and Usage Reports](http://aws.amazon.com/account/) section of your AWS account. Access to this can be granted via [IAM](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/ControllingAccessWebsite.html). You get detailed statistics for your whole usage there, although I don't think that you can break this down by bucket.

Another approach would be to use the [Amazon boto SDK in Python](https://github.com/boto/boto) to get the objects and their sizes. Or you can monitor the size of the storage during the uploads in your client software. With a combination of your total spending given with the method above and tracking the usage per client manually you can probably compute the amount of charges for every client.

Answer (score 0):

No its not possible to create a bucket for each user as Amazon allows only 100 buckets per account. So unless you are sure not to have more than 100 users, it will be a very bad idea.

The ideal solution will be to remember each user's storage in you Django app itself in database. I guess you would be using S3 boto library for storing the files, than it returns the byte size after each upload. You can use that to store that.

There is also another way out, you could create many folders inside a bucket with each folder specific to an user. But still the best way to remember the storage usage in your app